# ¿Como tener URL amigables (.htaccess en apache) con Lighttpd?

Tags: regex, lighttpd

Tengo este archivo de .htaccess:

```
(#)impedir que se pueda ver el listado de contenidos de un directorio
Options All -Indexes
(#)URL amigables
(#)activar RewriteEngine
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(\w+)$ index.php?accion=$1
RewriteRule ^(.*)&(.*)=(.*)$ index.php?accion=$1&$2=$3`
```

y quisiera saber como adaptarlo al servidor Lighttpd.

Answer (score 0):

Leyendo un poco en [la documentación](https://redmine.lighttpd.net/projects/1/wiki/docs_modrewrite), las reglas que publicaste se traducirían en:

```
url.rewrite-once = (
    "^/([^?]+)\?([^=&]+=[^=&]+)" => "/index.php?accion=$1&$2",
    "^/(\w+)$" => "/index.php?accion=$1"
)
```

Comment: Cuando coloco limproca/index.php?accion=almacenes obviamente funciona, pero los href los tengo acortados, al colocar limproca/almacenes dice 404 - Not Found.

Comment: @AngelZambrano es exactamente la misma regla que tenías en tu .htaccess. Si `limproca` no es la raíz de documentos, la regla debería ser `"^/limproca/(\w+)$" => "/limproca/index.php?accion=$1"`

Comment: Ya pude solucionarlo, es un poco diferente, hay que colocar la ruta completa del proyecto o sitio web:
`url.rewrite-once = ("^/index/limproca3.8/(\w+)$" =>"/index/limproca3.8/index.php?accion=$1",
 "^/index/limproca3.8/(.*)&(.*)=(.*)$" =>"/index/limproca3.8/index.php?accion=$1&$2=$3")`
mientras que en htaccess es un poco mas facil, pero ya esta solucionado, gracias por tu comentario.

Comment: Intente hacerlo sin colocar la ruta completa, pero es servidor lighttpd me generaba errores con otros servicios como PHPMyAdmin y PHP File Manager, estoy usando KSWEB en Adroid, supongo porque cuando leía cualquier ruta " / " la reescribia por la ruta limproca3.8 y salia #error 404.
En fin cada dia se aprenden cosas nuevas.

Comment: @AngelZambrano hay otras (muchas) opciones que te permiten establecer una ruta por defecto, o establecer reglas diferentes (un regex más genérico) que trabajen para cualquier ruta, o excepciones específicas (phpMyAdmin, etc). Para eso, te recomiendo leer la documentación de lighttpd... No obstante, eso ya escapa al contexto de tu pregunta original. De la forma que te respondí es exactamente como está en el .htaccess de Apache. Lo que hace que el .htaccess funcione en otra ruta es configurarle el `DocumentRoot`, cambiar el `RewriteBase`, o ponerlo en una carpeta específica.

Comment: Ya cree mi propio regex genérico para cualquier proyecto:

`url.rewrite-once =(
"^/index/(\w+|\W+\w|\w+\W+|\w+\d+\.\d+|\d+\.\d+\w+)/(\w+)$"=>
"/index/$1/index.php?accion=$2",
"^/index/(\d+.\w|\w+.\d\.\d|.*|\w+)/(.*)&(.*)=(.*)$"=>
"/index/$1/index.php?accion=$2&$3=$4")`

Para que acepte todo tipo de caracteres despues del /index/ en lighttpd.conf

Comment: @AngelZambrano ok. Aunque en ese caso, recomendaría algo más sencillo usando `[^/]+`, o sea cualquier cantidad de caracteres que no sean una barra... Sería `^/index/([^/]+)/(\w+)$` y `^/index/([^/]+)/([^/?]+)\?([^=&]+=[^=&]+)`... Sabés, este tipo de cuestiones escapan a tu pregunta original, y es mucho más sencillo y productivo si hicieras una nueva pregunta del tipo "*quiero reescribir páginas de cualquier carpeta como <varios ejemplos> a las siguientes páginas <resultado esperado>, intenté con <tu regex>, y está funcionando pero quería ver si se podía mejorar*" (algo así).